# How to store empty field in INT data type?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I store empty text in a INT data type? every time i submit the form it gives me a value of 0

here is my code:

```
$contact_number = $_POST['contact_num'];

$contact_number1 = !empty($contact_number) ? "'$contact_number'" : "NULL";

INSERT INTO 
pre_enrollment(pre_en_contact_num)
VALUES('$contact_number1');";
```

Comment: You cannot store text in INT.

Comment: NULL is your only option, if "contact_num" is a phone number, then you should not be using an int

Comment: @nogad what should i use then?

Comment: Use `NULL` as null, not a string with the value `null`.

Comment: phone numbers are strings, so varchar()

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can, remove the quotes. The quotes makes it a string.

```
$contact_number1 = !empty($contact_number) ? $_POST['contact_num'] : NULL;
```

Comment: i removed it and still gives me a value of 0

Comment: It needs to be unquoted in the SQL as well. Parameterize the query.

Comment: Yep the quotes make it a string.

Comment: `empty()` is evil! `empty("0")` is TRUE - but `"0"` it's not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have quotes in `$contact_number1`, you don't need them in the query. This is putting an extra set of quotes around the number, which is a syntax error, and putting quotes around `NULL`, which makes it a string instead of a null literal.

However, it would be best if you used a prepared query instead of string substitution.

```
$contact_number = empty($_POST['contact_num']) ? null : $_POST['contact_num'];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO pre_enrollment (pre_en_contact_num) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $contact_number);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

The prepared statement will automatically translate the PHP `null` to MySQL `NULL`.